# How can I set ID token lifetime for Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, adal

I'm using MSAL for users to login my React app. The ID token will be created in Frontend and sent to Backend for authentication.

However I've found out the ID token expiration time is 1 hour. I'm afraid that the app will log out users while they are in middle of their process in form filling out. Where can I set the expiration time to max 24hrs in Azure portal?

I cannot find it in the doc, it only said set in console.

Comment: Have you checked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.